# $watch over object new properties created dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a property on my angularjs controller that in my application is modified to have different properties but this properties are created dynamically. I need to add a `$watch` over each of those dynamically created properties and i don't know how to do it.

The property is created on the controller like this:

```
function FilterContentController($rootScope, $scope, filterOptions, $state, $stateParams, dataService) {
            var self = this;
            this.$scope = $scope;
            this.currentMobileFilters = {};
        }
```

Then i have a method `pushFilter`:

```
function (category, value) {
            var self = this;
            if (!self.currentMobileFilters[category]) {
                self.currentMobileFilters[category] = [];
            }
            if (self.isSelectedMobileFilterValue(category, value)) {
                // Remove
                self.currentMobileFilters[category] = _.without(self.currentMobileFilters[category], value);
            } else {
                // Add
                self.currentMobileFilters[category].push(value);
            }
        };
```

The `pushFilter` adds a new property over the `currentMobileFilters` object if doesn't exists with the name of the parameter `category` and then pushes over an array the parameter `value`. 
What i need to do is track the changes over the array's for each property created on `currentMobileFilters`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angular $watch method accepts a 3rd parameter for the type of equality watch.  See the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) under the $watch section.

Comment: Thank you for that info.. that was the solution, adding that third parameter with `true`